# Show buffer title at top of window instead of bottom

Tags: buffers, statusline, layout

By default vim shows the filename of the current buffer (or whatever status line you have specified) at the bottom of each split window. Is there any way to change it so that it displays at the top of each window instead?

Comment: no, not possible, if you want to have the statusline displayed at the top. you might be able to add something to the tabline, but the statusline will always be at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the title at the top of the window in a similar way to the statusline.  For example:

```
set title titlestring=%F
```

See `:help titlestring`.